# elisp: create window layout with specific cycling order

Tags: window, window-splitting

I'd like to create a window layout like so:

```
-----------|--------------
    a      |    b
-----------|--------------
    d      |    c 
-----------|--------------
```

This is so that I can cycle from a -> b -> c -> d (clockwise). The following doesn't quite work.. the cycling order is a -> d -> b -> c

```
(progn
  (delete-other-windows)
  (split-window-right)
  (other-window 1)
  (split-window-below)
  (other-window -1)
  (split-window nil nil 'above))
```

Comment: The function `window-in-direction` can be used to see if there is something 'above, 'below, 'left, 'right.  E.g, `(if (window-in-direction 'above) (select-window ....))`, and `(cond ((window-in-direction 'above) ...) ...)`.  The function `window-in-direction` returns the window it finds, or nil if none.  See the doc-string for more information regarding optional arguments, etc.  `M-x describe-function` aka `C-h f`.

Comment: There's no way to create windows that will be ordered in such way. If you want to cycle through them that way, you'll need to write a custom window movement command.